# How to update frame of view in cell

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a cell that has 1 label inside it.

I want when to show this label left then right, then left, then right...

Here is my code:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleData: UILabel!

    var data: String? {
        didSet {
            titleData.text = data ?? ""
            if alternativeMode {
                titleData.frame.origin.x = (row % 2 != 0) ? 200 : 0
            } else {
                titleData.frame.origin.x = 200
            }
            layoutSubviews()
        }
    }

    var row: Int!
    var alternativeMode = false

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
        self.selectionStyle = .none
    }

}
```

But this label doesn't show alternative.

Comment: Are you using autolayout? if so, that won't work. also, call `setNeedsLayout` instead of `layoutSubviews` to let iOS layout in it's own time. The quickest way I can think to solve your issue is to use a label spanning over the full width and just change the alignment of the label, no layout required.

Comment: I have solved this, but your suggestion: `The quickest way I can think to solve your issue is to use a label spanning over the full width and just change the alignment of the label, no layout required` is good +1.

Comment: glad I could help!

Comment: if you've solved your problem then you should post an answer to your own question and then up-vote it. That way others know you've got an answer, and it's documented in case somebody else has the same problem.

Comment: @DuncanC, I have just posted my answer.

Comment: Aside: Khuong, I notice that quite a lot of [your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4742830+help+is%3Aquestion) are fairly wordy, and contain variations on a theme of `What I do wrong here / Please help me with this / Any helps would be appreciated / Thanks`. Since you're an experienced user, one of the things you might have noticed about other questions is they are well received if they are succinct, and editors often trim them to make them even shorter.

Comment: Additionally, it is worth bearing in mind that it is very clear when you post a question that you want help, so `please help me` is sometimes interpreted as a form of begging, which we get a lot of anyway, and it often results in downvotes. So, if you wouldn't mind leaving this out of your questions, it will reduce the amount of editing we need to do, and will make your questions easier to parse. Thanks!

Comment: @halfer, thanks for your comment. I will learn from experience.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem in another approach

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleData: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleDataTrailingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var data: String? {
        didSet {
            titleData.text = data ?? ""
        }
    }

    var row: Int! 
    var alternativeMode = false 

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if titleDataTrailingConstraint != nil {
            let screenSizeWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
            if alternativeMode {
                titleDataTrailingConstraint.constant = (row % 2 == 0) ? (screenSizeWidth - titleData.bounds.width - 80) : 10
            } else {
                titleDataTrailingConstraint.constant = 10
            }
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
        self.selectionStyle = .none
    }

}
```

Comment: Yup, that is the approach I was going to suggest.